# Disable multilingual option in Apache tiles 3

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, apache-tiles, tiles-3

I am getting following warning with Apche tiles 3 and Spring MVC 4 I does not added any extra configurations for multilingual support but it supporting by default. Can any one help me to disable this option to remove this warning in my site.

```
    org.apache.tiles.request.locale.PostfixedApplicationResource.
<init> No supported matching language for locale "sw". 
Using file:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tiles/app-core_sw.xml as a non-localized resource path. see TILES-571
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable this option by writing your own `DefinitionFactory` implementation and registering the same in `TilesConfigurer`.

```
public class CustomLocaleDefinitionsFactory extends LocaleDefinitionsFactory {

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public Definition getDefinition(String name, Request tilesContext) {
    Definition retValue;
    Locale locale = null;

    retValue = definitionDao.getDefinition(name, locale);
    if (retValue != null) {
      retValue = new Definition(retValue);
      String parentDefinitionName = retValue.getExtends();
      while (parentDefinitionName != null) {
        Definition parent = definitionDao.getDefinition(parentDefinitionName, locale);
        if (parent == null) {
          throw new NoSuchDefinitionException("Cannot find definition '" + parentDefinitionName
              + "' ancestor of '" + retValue.getName() + "'");
        }
        retValue.inherit(parent);
        parentDefinitionName = parent.getExtends();
      }
    }

    return retValue;
    }
}
```

And then in register the above definition factor class, in `TilesConfigurer` in case using spring like this.

```
TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
configurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/layouts/tiles.xml",
    "/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml" });
configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
configurer.setDefinitionsFactoryClass(CustomLocaleDefinitionsFactory.class);
return configurer;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround, just disable the log output will do, if you are using spring boot, it is very easy:

```
logging.level.org.apache.tiles.request.locale.PostfixedApplicationResource=ERROR
```